# Why doesn't my Haskell cmd line program get arguments from Vim Bang?

Tags: haskell, vim

Vim has the possibility to let you replace selected text with the output of an external program. I'd like to take advantage of this with programs that I'd write in Haskell. But it doesn’t get the selected text as args.

-- show-input.hs

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

main = do
    input <- getArgs
    putStr ("Input was: " ++ (show input))
```

When I run it from the command line (NixOS GNU/Linux, BASH), I get the expected behavior:

```
$ ./show-input test
Input was: ["test"]
```

When I select some text in Vim and invoke `:'<,'>!~/show-input`, I get this :

```
Input was: []
```

There is something weird here, but I can't tell if it is from the way Vim passes arguments or from the way Haskell gets them. I have tried with both console Vim and graphical gVim (8.0.1451), with the same result.

---

NB: I can successfully use Vim Bang! with other external programs, such as grep. It works great.

### ---

## Correct version after chepner's answer

So, for anyone interested, just replace `getArgs` with `getContents` and you get your input all in a string (instead of a list of strings).

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

main = do
    input <- getContents
    putStr ("Input was: " ++ (show input))
```

Comment: I recommend moving the solution you appended to the question to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` command sends the seleted text to the program via standard input, not as a command line argument. The command line equivalent would be `somecommand | ./show-input`.

Comment: Thanks. I was misled with a comparison to grep, which (as it seem), can take both arguments and data from the standard input.

Comment: Even with `grep`, there is a slight difference. The argument(s) to `grep` are names of files to read from in lieu of standard input, not the actual data that will be filtered. `grep 'f*' bar foo` doesn't output `foo`; it tries to read from files named `bar` and `foo`.